# Android accessibility: How to remove widget class name from talkback?

Tags: android, accessibility

By default, when a content description is set for a widget, Talkback service adds widget's class name to it, i.e. for:

```
button.setContentDescription("blah")
```

Talkback will say "blah button". Is there a way to prevent it from saying class name? I've tried overriding initialization of AccessibilityNodeInfo and AccessibilityEvent through custom AccessibilityDelegate, but with no luck.

If not, is it possible to add more text after Talkback says "button"?

Comment: I would imagine that the class name is important, to help the user know how to use the widget.

Comment: Agree, and I have "button" inside of my content description. As an alternative, I can come up with a description such that the "button" at the end will fit, but out app is also localized in French, and I don't know if I can do the same there.